# Beginner question about video predict Yolo8

Tags: yolo, yolov8

Just starting with Python / YoloV8. I managed to create a custom model, and now I am testing with it. Can you please help a n00b out?

I trained it on image size 1024:

```
model.train(data='data.yaml', epochs=200, imgsz=1024, device=0)
```

I use this code to start a prediction (Python on Windows):

```
import os
import torch
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO(r"C:\yolo\License Plates.v3i.yolov8-v3\best.pt")

#For video
model.predict(source=r"C:\yolo\testvideo.mp4", show=True)
#For image
model.predict(source=r"C:\yolo\testimag.jpg", show=True)
```

Problems I encounter:

- The preview window (showing the image or video) cannot be closed. Windows says the window isn't responding. I need to enter exit() on the Python console to exit everything. Pressing/holding "Q" or CTRL-C doesn't help either.
- When using photos / videos with a larger resolution than 1024px, the preview Window is cropped. How to prevent this? How to pre-crop the media to 1024*1024 or how to make yolo use/show a larger resolution?

I hope you can answer my basic questions! Thanks in advance.